# Multiplying and Dividing by Two

Tags: java, loops, bessel-functions

Why are these two snippets of code giving two different results?

```
    double sum = 1.0;
    double xSqFour = x * x / 4;

    for (int i = 48; i > 1; i-=2) {
        sum = 1.0 + (xSqFour / ((i/2) * (i/2))) * sum;
    }

    return sum;
```

and

```
    double sum = 1.0;
    double xSqFour = x * x / 4;

    for (int i = 24; i > 1; i--) {
        sum = 1.0 + (xSqFour / (i * i)) * sum;
    }

    return sum;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bounds error on your second loop.  It should be `i > 0`.  The first loop has `i > 1`, but it also divides `i` by 2.  `1 / 2 == 0`, so it should be `i > 0` in the second loop.

Comment: Gee, thanks!  (I'm headdesking now, as that should've been obvious.)  Will accept in 5 minutes.

Comment: It's purely a bounds thing, and has nothing to do with the `i/2` bit, the OP is decrementing by 2 in the first instance; here's an example of what's going on: http://ideone.com/uIqDI